# Change navigation styles depending on current path in Gatsby.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

With require(), I can get the CSS switching from page A to page B ... but when returning to page A, it keeps the stylesheet from page B active, even though both pages require() their own specific stylesheet. The same happens when I require() stylesheets by comparing to the current URL (location.pathname). What is the easiest way to accomplish this in Gatsby?

What I've tried:

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import Header from '../components/Home/Header'
import style from "../templates/module.main.css";

const IndexPage = () => {

  return (
    <Layout className={style}>
      <Header />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import Header from '../components/Home/Header'
import style from "../templates/module.secondary.css";

const IndexPageTwo = () => {

  return (
    <Layout className={style}>
      <Header />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default IndexPageTwo
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use css module**, it will link the style to the pages/components.

Example with scss:

styleA.module.scss:

```
.page {
background: red
}
```

PageA.tsx:

```
import style from "./styleA.module.scss";
export default () => <div className={style.page}>Test</div>
```

---

styleB.module.scss:

```
.page {
background: blue
}
```

PageB.tsx:

```
import style from "./PageB.module.scss";
export default () => <div className={style.page}>Test</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me try that.

Comment: I still have the problem when returning to page A, it keeps the stylesheet from page B active. Is that cause im using CSS instead of SASS?

Comment: share your code please, css or scss does not affect this behavior

Comment: You can see the updated code above in my question.

Comment: I used two styledsheets, but when im changing paths it's keeping the first stylesheet active

Comment: you can't use className={style}, you have to provide a class. If you need to change a theme, you can use the localStorage to store the theme.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Are there other ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think the best solution for me was using react helmet and targeting the class like that:

```
<Helmet bodyAttributes={{ class: 'pageTwo' }} />
```

and then

```
.pageTwo .navbar {
   color: black;
}
```